# Composition of Random Variables?

Tags: statistics

Given some family of distributions with each distribution determined by a set of parameters, is it possible (in a canonical way) to substitute another random variable for a subset of each of these parameters (making the distributions in a sense more random)?

Comment: Not quite sure to completely understand what you mean (in particular by "canonical"), but for instance replacing the $n$ of a Binomial distribution by a Poisson r.v. $N$ yields a [compound Poisson.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution)

Comment: You mean something like a normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are random variables?